# Visual Studio 2019 .NET 4.6 WinForms solution changes appearance between computers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I am working with 2 colleagues on a project. It is a Windows Forms project, and I am noticing an issue that I haven't ever seen before with other projects / programming languages or IDEs.

We do a commit to GIT, one of the other guys pulls the code, does his changes, and a lot of things are changed besides the code that has been touched. Variable names such as styling variables for grids, sizes for grid headers and other things which were not changed while the other developer was modifying code, and when he commited the changes, there were multiple changes regarding element sizes (width and height) and the UI of the app became completely different from what it was before the commit.

Why is this happening? How can we get around this?

We are using Visual Studio Community 2019, version 16.2.5.

This is a perfect example of what happened. Visual studio code just changed the name of the variables, and when you pull in another machine, it just breaks the build:

[image]

Just to provide an insight of what happened, have a look at the summary from git. I can guarantee that no one changed 1% of these settings, let alone 1000 lines in a single file:

[image]

Comment: Someone must have altered the designer code.

Comment: Are all developers using the same screen resolution?

Comment: @Amy what does that mean? Modified as in went to the file and changed the code explicitly? If that is what you are referring to, then no.

Comment: @LarsTech 2 of them are, 1 no. But I have seen this last friday with 2 monitors of the same resolution, and now with 2 of different. Regardless, I don't see a reason for changing variable names.

Comment: @BlunT Modifying anything in the form designer will result in a modification to the designer code.  Git certainly isn't going to alter your code.

Comment: @BlunT What variables have been altered?  Can you be any more specific and share some code with us and how it was changed?

Comment: @Amy sure I have a lot of examples. We squashed the changes from Friday that caused the exact same issue, but we have a lot from today. I left them in the question.

Comment: @Amy sorry but I missed one of your messages. I am not blaming GIT, I am blaming Visual Studio. I know for a fact that GIT does not do this, we use GIT with different programming languages, IDEs and in different projects. This only happens with Visual Studio, not GIT.

Comment: @BlunT You have **one** close vote and a few comments asking for more information, added *before* you had anything in your question to look at.

Comment: If you just changed the environment and not related to code, I suggest that you could report a problem in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Comment: thank you @JackJJun-MSFT will do that